# Reinstall XOrg with Yum - Fedora 18

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, yum

Some how I messed up Xorg and need to reinstall it, with Yum. I can not find any Xorg packages, but it has to be out there right?

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora, Xorg is a lot ot packages with names starting `xorg-x11-`.

You can try `rpm -Va`, that will give a list of files that `rpm` considers modified from the original install. Check the list (it includes configuration files that are changed and others that are adjusted for your machine), `rpm -qf <filenames>` gives the list of packages containing those files, `yum reinstall <packages>` reinstalls them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to do a:

```
yum groupremove "X Window System"
```

Then make sure all residual Xorg-related files are removed and then doing a:

```
yum groupinstall "X Window System"
```

I haven't tested the above procedure on Fedora, but it's situations like this that justify them having software group commands.

Answer (score 0):

There is no group called "X Window System" anymore, so that will not work.
Perhaps the best would be:
rpm -qa|grep xorg > a
rpm -e --nodeps `cat a`
that will remove the lot.
Now edit a and get rid of the version part, and try
yum install `cat a`